# Inline if-else with big chunks of code in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, jsx

I have 2 chunks of code I want to switch between conditional and I prefer to do it inline, but it seems this syntax is not correct:

```
const chunk1 = (...)
const chunk2 = (...)

{this.state.condition ? (
  {chunk1}
) : (
  {chunk2}
)}
```

I get:

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object
>   with keys {loginOptions}). If you meant to render a collection of
>   children, use an array instead or wrap the object using
>   createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method
>   of `Card`.

What would be the correct way?

Comment: Issue is not with ternary operator. Its with `chunk`

Comment: When I load each chunk separately, without the wrapping if-else they work fine

Comment: Try creating a function that returns necessary chunk based on condition and call this function on render. This will also clean your render method

Comment: I already tried it and it worked fine. This is just more expressive in my case and I don't undertrained why there is an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your syntax is wrong. Try this instead:

```
{this.state.condition ? 
  chunk1
: 
  chunk2
}
```

Or

```
  if (condition) {
    content = chunk1;
  } else {
    content = chunk2;
  }

{content}
```

ES7 do:

```
const content = (data) => do {
  if (data) chunk1
  else chunk2
}

{content}
```

More info

[Official React documentation for Conditional rendering](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Comment: Yes exactly. Glad I helped.

Answer (score 0):

I currently like to format my ternaries like this in react:

```
render () {
  return (
    <div className="row">
      { //Check if message failed
        (this.state.message === 'failed')
          ? <div> Something went wrong </div> 
          : <div> Everything in the world is fine </div> 
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the chunk of code is JSX elements only, you can do it like

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    state = {condition: false}
    
    render() {
      var chunk1 = (<div>Hello World</div>)
      var chunk2 = (<div>Hello React</div>)
      return (
          <div>{this.state.condition? chunk1 : chunk2}</div>
      )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```